# xPath how to access input text file with generic name

Tags: xpath

Is there any option to access input in code like this:

```
(...)
<div class="dialogProp">
    <div class="gwt-Label">Name</div> 
    <div class="floatLeft">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="textBox">
        </div> 
    <div class="notVisible"></div>
</div>
<div class="dialogProp">
    <div class="gwt-Label">Surname</div> 
    <div class="floatLeft">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="textBox">
        </div> 
    <div class="notVisible"></div>
</div>
(...)
```

As you can see I got two inputs and only difference between them is label inside of div with different text inside. This kind of pattern can be found all around of website and I cannot change this. I can not add id's as well.
Do you know if there is possibility to add to the xPath this different text inside of div's?

Let's say I would like to access first input.

Of course I could use some ass long xPath, but I would like to reuse this with text inside of gwt-Label as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the *input* with respect to the *label text* you can use the following solution:

```
labelText = "Name" 
#or labelText = "Surname"
xpath = "//div[@class='gwt-Label' and contains(.,'" +labelText+ "')]//following::div[1]//input"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below to locate `input` by label text:

```
//div[@class="gwt-Label" and .="Name"]/following-sibling::div//input
```

In Python you can pass label from variable:

```
label = "Name"
xpath = '//div[@class="gwt-Label" and .="%s"]/following-sibling::div//input' % label
```